# How do you solve this calculus maxima minima problem graphically, without calculus?

Tags: linear-algebra

A rectangular paddock is to be fenced using a river as one boundary. The paddock is to have an area of $8000$ m. Let one side of the paddock be $$ then use a suitable graph to determine the minimum amount of fencing required.

Do I introduce another variable? I am confused because it only tells me to introduce one ($x$).So I have $xy = 8000$ and $x + 2y = P$. I sketched $y = \frac{8000}{x}$ and I assume for $P$ to be minimized, it must touch at a tangent. Please help me find these coordinates as this is where I get stuck - there are three variables now ?! And there isn't enough information to label my graphs

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $y = \frac{8000}{x}$ to eliminate $y$ in your equation for perimeter.

Comment: yes I have done that. Via quadratic formula, it gives me an x -int but in terms of P. That doesn't really help though

Comment: You should have gotten $P = x + \frac{16000}{x}$.  Remember that you're trying to find where $P$ has a minimum, that shouldn't involve solving a quadratic in terms of $P$.

Comment: yes well then If I sketch this, I still wont be able to find the minimum value without calculus

Comment: @user71207, if you plot from $x=100$ to $x=150$ you can ballpark the minimum value using a graph.

Comment: Here's a plot from wolframalpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%2B16000%2Fx+from+x%3D120+to+x%3D135

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put an imaginary wall perpendicular to the river through the center of a paddock, you will find two areas of 4000 m² with two identical fence walls with lengthes x and y, so $xy=4000$. The half-perimeter of the whole fence is $P=x+y$.

On a coordinate plane, $x+y=P$ gives you a line at $45°$, whereas $xy=4000$ gives you a hyperbola. When $P$ is small, line doesn't cross hyperbola, when you increase $P$ the line will move parallelly and at some point will touch it. From the symmetry of both curves, one can see that it will happen at point $x=y$, thus $x=y=\sqrt{4000}$. And perimeter is $2(x+y)$

Comment: If $x$ is the length of the long side of the rectangle, how can $x$ also be used in xy=4000??? Should it not be $\frac{x}{2} y = 4000$

Comment: I used x as a half of long side

Comment: Thank you. The symmetry fact was really insightful. This only works for basic monic linear equations right? Because for my way, the linear equation was $y = \frac{-x}{2} + ... $So it is unsolvable my way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.

You know that

$P = x+2y$

$P = \frac{2x+4y}{2}$

So P is the arithmetic mean of $2x$ and $4y$.

The geometric mean of $2x$ and $4y$ is

$\sqrt{(2x)(4y)} = \sqrt{8xy} = \sqrt{64000} = 80\sqrt{10}$

We know the arithmetic mean is greater than or equal to the geometric mean. So the minimum possible fencing is $80\sqrt{10}$.

The minimum occurs when $2x=4y$ ie: $x=2y$.

Comment: Interesting. I would have not expected this at all